# Spring data mongodb custom query, get by a list of nested property

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

I have a following dtos and rest repository of `Person`

**DTOs**

```java
class Person {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private List<Address> addresses;
    private Status status;
}
```

```java
class Address {
    private String id;
    private String addressLineOne;
    private String addressLineTwo;
}
```

```java
enum Status {
    ACTIVE, INACTIVE
}
```

**Spring Data REST repository**

```java
@RestResource(path = "byAddresses")
@Query("{'$and': [{'status': 'ACTIVE'}, {'addresses.id' : {'$in' : ?1}}]}")
Page<Person> findByAddresses(List<String> ids, Pageable pageable);
```

I want to get persons by addresses list. For an example lets say there are 3 addresses in the list. If 5 people are using at least one of the addresses from that, all 5 people should be there in the results. How can I changes this query to to achieve that?

Comment: Try: `'$in' : ?0` or `@Query("{'status': 'ACTIVE', 'addresses.id' : {'$in' : ?0}}")`

Comment: @Valijon that was a silly mistake :/ Thanks for pointing that out